# Strange symbols stopping my batch file running in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, batch-file

I am trying to create and run a batch file from VB.net, then get the output and print it out. But when it runs it is appended by these symbols '´╗┐. Causing this error '´╗┐cd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. When I look at the batch file in notepad++ there is no symbol there! What is happening! Thanks James.

Code:

```
    Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Dim command As String = "cd " & path & " & " & argument

    MsgBox(command)

    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(tempFile, False)
    file.WriteLine("@ECHO OFF")
    file.WriteLine(command)
    file.Close()

    Dim objProcess As New Process()
    Dim SROutput As System.IO.StreamReader

    With objProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = tempFile
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .Arguments = ""
    End With
    objProcess.Start()
    SROutput = objProcess.StandardOutput

    Do While SROutput.Peek <> -1
        'MessageBox.Show(SROutput.ReadLine)
        rtbOutput.Text = rtbOutput.Text & SROutput.ReadLine & vbNewLine
    Loop
    objProcess.Dispose()

    'Process.Start(tempFile)
    rtbOutput.Text = rtbOutput.Text & message & vbNewLine
```

Comment: That looks like the unicode BOM (byte-order mark).  Try opening the file with `..OpenTextFileWriter(tempFile, False, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

It means the `OpenTextFileWriter()` method is using a different encoding than you expect. You can fix the problem by using [`OpenTextFileWriter()` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128024(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you pick an encoding like ASCII with no byte order mark or use the encoding with the byte order mark that matches what the DOS subsystem is expecting.

Comment: As I said in my own answer I solved it with an alternate solution. But thanks for this info and fix for future reference! Its much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Im not entirely sure what was happening when it was writing the file, but I have changed it to this

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(tempFile)
        writer.Write(command)
End Using
```

and its now running fine!. Thanks for any time spent on this and feel free to post an explination as to why this was happening.